# Creating user and appending stats

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a bit of trouble working on a game project, attempting to create a user creation prompt when the user starts a new game, and creating a new user if the username entered doesn't already exit, else appending stats if the username already exists. Those stats being wins, losses, draws that are appended to the users stats.

So I've only been able to think of two options, first is to create a dictionary with the username as key and a nested list for their stat values, or otherwise to create a class with the username function and functions for each list such as wins list, losses list, etc.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Jan 28 Edit:

As per request for code, I'll post segments of what I have and what I'm looking to accomplish...

Part 1 - Username creation:

```
    while True:
  playerinput = input("Please type a number correlating with your menu choice, or 4 to return to main menu: ")

  if playerinput == "1":
      game_range = range(1, 10)
      play_the_game(playerinput, game_range)
  elif playerinput == "2":
      game_range = range(1, 26)
      play_the_game(playerinput, game_range)
  elif playerinput == "3":
      game_range = range(1, 28)
      play_the_game(playerinput, game_range)
  elif playerinput == "4":
      exec(open("menuitems.py").read(), globals())
  else:
      print("Unknown input: ", playerinput, ", please try again")
```

At this point of starting a new game (I've left the menu items out to cut down on the code size here) by selecting a menu option, I want for it to ask the user to enter a username at this point, and either create a new user if it doesn't already exist, or append to it with the stats.

Part 2 - User stats (this is a big part of code):

```
def play_the_game(playerinput, game_range):
while True:
    board = [" "] * (max(game_range) + 1)
    plays = []
    player_icon, computer_icon = player_choice()
    turn = who_goes_first()
    print(turn + " will get the first turn of the game")
    game_in_play = True

    while game_in_play:
        if turn == "player":
            print_the_board(board, playerinput)
            print("""
            Computer: Choose your move carefully, human
            """)
            print("Enter your move between ", min(game_range), "-", max(game_range), ", ", min(game_range),
                    " for top left, ", max(game_range), " for bottom right")
            player_move = input("Enter your move: ")
            if player_move == "e":
                break
            if player_move == "u":
                if len(plays) == 0:
                    print("No more moves left to undo - you cheated your way back to the beginning!")
                    continue
                print("I shouldn't be letting you do this - it really feels like cheating...")
                player_move = plays.pop()
                board[player_move] = " "
                player_move = plays.pop()
                board[player_move] = " "
                continue
            if not player_move.isdigit():
                AI_insults()
                continue
            if int(player_move) not in game_range or not free_space_on_board(board, int(player_move)):
                AI_insults()
                continue

            make_a_move(board, player_icon, int(player_move))
            plays.append(int(player_move))

            if win_condition(board, player_icon, playerinput):
                print_the_board(board, playerinput)
                print("Congrats! You beat that pesky computer!")
                game_in_play = False
            else:
                if draw_condition(board, game_range):
                    print_the_board(board, playerinput)
                    print("It's a draw!")
                    break
                else:
                    turn = "Computer"

        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer_icon, playerinput, game_range)
            plays.append(move)
            make_a_move(board, computer_icon, move)

            if win_condition(board, computer_icon, playerinput):
                print_the_board(board, playerinput)
                AI_endgame_brag()
                game_in_play = False

            else:
                if draw_condition(board, game_range):
                    print_the_board(board, playerinput)
                    print("It's a draw!")
                    break
                else:
                    turn = "player"
    if not end_game():
        break
```

I've left out a whole lot of functions used in that code to again try keeping this small, but what I want to accomplish is so that should "win_condition" for the player be fulfilled, then it appends +1 to the users win stats, if "draw_condition", then +1 to draw stats, and if the computer wins, well +1 to loss.

I have another section of menu code where the player can opt to check the statistics of users, where I'll be wanting to print the username, their wins, losses and draws.

So far I'm thinking a dictionary would be the best option with an if this username exists in the dictionary - then use this key and append to its values, else create new key, etc...

Comment: Please show us your code, what you have tried, what the inputs are, what the outputs are, what the expected outputs are.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Good news! I thought of a solution to my problem which was actually quite a simple solution that looks like this...

```
with open("users.json", "r") as f:
  try:
    user_dict = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    user_dict = {}
username = input("Please enter a username to create a new user, or to access an existing user: ")
if username not in user_dict:
  user_dict[username] = [0, 0, 0]
```

Then following a win, draw, loss etc, I've added this code to the game code following each win/lose condition etc before the break.

```
                if win_condition(board, player_icon, playerinput):
                  print_the_board(board, playerinput)
                  print("Congrats! You beat that pesky computer!")
                  user_dict[username][0] += 1
                  game_in_play = False
```

Having added the "user_dict[username][index] += 1", where I'll simply use index 0 for wins, index 1 for losses, and 3 for draws.

And I've now added a bit of code into the function that's triggered when the game ends that looks like this...

```
    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(user_dict, f)
```

It works perfectly with persistent stats tied to usernames now, thanks Stack for the JSON commands I found around here...